ECS Task is taking too long to start, Status is in "Provisioning"
I have a React.js application which I can run locally in Docker with Kubernetes, however I want to deploy this application in the AWS ECS, with EC2 managed launch type. I have pushed the image into ECR, created task definitions with the image URI in the ECS, and made a Cluster referring to the task definition, However the task is not getting launched, it is still in "Provisioning" mode though I have selected the default permission which popped up (ecsTaskExecutionRole
-> AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy) while creating the cluster, which is as below,
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Are the permissions enough? Where are the permissions for running the ECS task defined (though I can see permissions to get the Docker image from the ECR)? Any help would be appreciated.

EC2 instance Dashboard

Cloud Formation Dashboard


Do you have any EC2 instances actually registered with the ECS cluster? You need to look around in the ECS console for reasons it isn't able to place the task.

There are 2 EC2 instances started provisioned by the ECS - Auto Scaling Group and is Ready. @MarkB. Also the CloudFormation is still in ECSService - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS

Do the EC2 instances meet the size requirements defined in the ECS task? Does it actually say in the ECS cluster that those instances are connected to the cluster? It is very common to get the network configuration wrong, so that provisioned EC2 instances can't connect to the cluster, so no tasks can be placed on them.

@MarkB, You are right, I believe the EC2 instances are not yet associated with the ECS Cluster, since the Cloud formation is still stuck at creating the ECSService - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS status. But I wonder, then, who made the EC2 instances.

Without sharing your CloudFormation code or whatever, I can't answer who created the EC2 instances. It sounds like ECS created the instances, via the capacity provider (if you configured one), but you may have some network configuration incorrect, so the EC2 instances can't connect to the cluster once they are started, so everything is stuck.

It likely isn't provisioning forever, but instead is failing to provision and attempting to provision new tasks.
On your first screenshot in the dropdown "Filter desired status", select Stopped instead of Running and you will see previous tasks that failed to provision.
Click on one of the failed tasks to see a reason for the failure which should help you investigate further.
